# Multiplying two polynomials

Tags: algorithm

This is a question asked in some interview questions.

Given three polynomials f(x), g(x), h(x) where the co-efficient are binary. Give [f(x)*g(x)] mod h(x) [All operation in binary co-efficient]

Polynomials are given in this format… x3 + x + 1 is given as “1011”. Write a program char* multmod (char *f, char *g, char *h) that will output polynomial… (f*g) mod h

What could be the approach?
can we do something at bit level?

Comment: *Attention: the following leading questions are intended for the original poster.* Can you add two polynomials? How is this operation on binary polynomials different from one on regular polynomials? Can you multiply an arbitrary polynomial by `x^17`? Do you know how to do polynomial long division?

Comment: Yes, binary operations of XOR and shifts should do the trick. What some are missing is that the coefficients are _binary_, that is to say in the field Z_2. This means `(x^3 + x^2 + 1) + (x^2) = (x^3 + 2x^2 + 1) = (x^3 + 1)` or `1101 XOR 0100 = 1001`!

Answer (score 19):

**Motivation**

Binary coefficients here means that the coefficients are modulo 2, in the field Z_2, or just take on the values 0 and 1 and operate like bits. It does not mean the coefficients are arbitrary integers represented in base two. They *are* binary (take on exactly two values), as opposed to simply being expressed in a binary numeral system.

With this firmly in mind, this question is fairly easy to answer, and yes, bitwise operations of XOR and (left) shifts will suffice. Though not required to answer this question, this question is motivated by cryptography. It demonstrates the link between some bitwise operations commonly used in hashing and some encryption schemes and abstract algebra, so that results about polynomials over finite fields can be leveraged in cryptanalysis. Taking the product modulo another polynomial is to prevent the degree of the result from growing past a certain limit. Operations on machine registers do this naturally as overflow.

**Addition**

First let’s talk about addition. As the coefficients are modulo 2, adding `x + x = 2x = 0x = 0` since `2 mod 2 = 0`. So, whenever there is two of the same term, they cancel, and when there is only one it persists. This is the same behavior as `XOR`. For example, adding `(x^4 + x^2 + 1) + (x^3 + x^2):`

```
(1x^4+0x^3+1x^2+0x^1+1x^0)+(0x^4+1x^3+1x^2+0x^1+0x^0) = (1x^4+1x^3+0x^2+0x^1+1x^0)
```

or, using the compact coefficient only notation,

```
10101 XOR 01100 = 11001
```

**Multiplication**

Multiplication by `x` increases the power of each term by one. In the compact notation, this is equivalent to left bitwise shift.

```
(1x^4+0x^3+1x^2+0x^1+1x^0) * x = (1x^5+0x^4+1x^3+0x^2+1x^1+0x^0)
10101 << 1 = 101010
```

So, to multiply polynomials `f(x) * g(x)` we can multiply `f(x)` by each term of `g(x)` separately, each being equivalent to a shift, and then add, the addition being equivalent to XOR. Let’s multiply `(x^4 + x^2 + 1) * (x^3 + x^2)`

```
(x^4 + x^2 + 1) * (x^3 + x^2) = (x^4 + x^2 + 1)*x^3 + (x^4 + x^2 + 1) *x^2
(10101 << 3) XOR (10101 << 2) = 10101000 XOR 01010100 = 11111100
```

So, the answer is `x^7 + x^6 + x^5 + x^4 + x^3 + x^2`.

**Modulo Reduction**

Reduction modulo `h(x)` is also fairly easy. It certainly does *not* require you to remember how to do long division. Like multiplication, we’ll do it term by term. Let’s continue with the same example, and take it modulo `h(x) = x^5 + x`

```
(x^7 + ... + x^2) mod (x^5+x) = [x^7 mod (x^5+x)] + ... + [x^2 mod (x^5+x)]
```

Now, if the degree, `n`, of `x^n` is smaller than that of `h(x)`, here 5, then there is nothing to be done because `h(x)` won’t divide `x^n`.

```
[x^2 mod (x^5+x)] = x^2 or 00000100
[x^3 mod (x^5+x)] = x^3 or 00001000
[x^4 mod (x^5+x)] = x^4 or 00010000
```

When then degrees are equal, we can say `h(x)` divides `x^n` one time, and we have overshot by the remaining terms of `h(x)`. That we’ve overshot instead of undershot hardly matters, nor does the sign on remainder since `-1 mod 2 = 1`. Here,

```
x^5 = (x^5 + x) – x, so
[x^5 mod (x^5+x)] = x, or 00000010
```

In general, [x^n mod h(x)] = [h(x)-x^n] when `n = degree(h)`. In compact form, this is equivalent to turning off the `n`th bit, which can be done by XOR-ing the representation of `h(x)` with the representation of `x^n`:

```
00100010 XOR 00100000 = 00000010.
```

When `x^n` has a degree larger than `h(x)` we can multiply `h(x)` by `x^k` to make the degrees match, and proceed as in the prior case.

x^6 = (x^5 + x)*x – (x)*x = -x^2, so
   [x^6 mod (x^5+x)] = x^2, or 00000100, or in compact form
   (00100010 << 1) XOR (00100000 << 1) = 00000100

But, more efficiently, just shift the previous answer, which we’ll do for `x^7`:

```
[x^7 mod (x^5+x)] = x^3, or 00001000
```

So to collect, we need to add these results, which is XOR-ing in the compact representation.

```
x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x + x^2 + x^3 = x^4 + 2x^3 + 2x^2 + x = x^4 + x, or
00000100 XOR 00001000 XOR 00010000 XOR 00000010 XOR 00000100 XOR 00001000 = 00010010
```

**Concluding Remarks**

We can ask [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28x%5E4+%2B+x%5E2+%2B+1%29+*+%28x%5E3+%2B+x%5E2%29%29++%2F+%28x%5E5%2Bx%29) to verify this result for us by long division. The remainder given is `x^4 - x`, which is equivalent to `x^4 + x` when the coefficients are modulo 2.

The term-by-term multiplication and modulo steps may be combined, e.g. multiply by `x` and modulo the product, for a more efficient algorithm, which will be a shift and XOR if the product’s degree is at least that of `h(x)`. Then repeat on the result, multiply by `x` and modulo the product, and record that answer for multiplication by `x^2`. And so forth...

Answer (score 0):

This is a knowledge question. Basically, unless you either are as smart as Gauss or you already know congruence mathematics, also known as "modular arithmetic", you are screwed. One book you may want to read to learn about this stuff is "Introduction to Number Theory with Computing" by Allenby.

Ultimately the key knowledge is that the congruence can be calculated by several methods, the best of which is the "square and multiply" method which is quite ancient. Basically, whenever you have a binary 1 you both square and multiple, but when you have a 0, you just square. The complete algorithm and explanation is on p. 79 of Allenby.

Another approach would use the Chinese Remainder Thereom, which is probably what the questioner was aiming at.

Where are you applying? The NSA? Los Alamos? That is a pretty tough question.

---

Great, downvoted for being the only person who actually answered the question. Just to be clear here: undoubtedly the interviewer was expecting exploitation of the square and multiply algorithm, as I said above. Square and multiply is used inside of RSA/cryptography algorithms to do fast modulo operations. See p. 225 for a description of this algorithm and RSA application: [Implementation of Multinomial Standard Product for RSA State](http://www.ijrcct.org/index.php/ojs/article/download/75/59). The interviewer probably worked on RSA which is why he knew of the method.

Comment: In my day this would be a high-school-level question. It is easily answerable if you know how to divide two polynomials and get a remainder. It's a long, long way from there to NSA.

Comment: @n.m. - precisely. You are making this sound way more complicated than it really is Tyler. I had one of these on my 11th grade algebra exam.

Comment: This is actually pretty easy. It is, however, highly relevant to cryptography and the NSA... If you pay attention to the fact that coefficients are binary (that is, in Z_2 and reduce modulo 2 themselves) then you'll see that addition is XOR and multiplication by x^n is a bit shift.

Comment: ...so, if you have a great amount of knowledge and results on the algebra of finite fields and polynomials then you can apply those to study the algebra of binary operations. But, to simply execute those binary operations, you need not know very much at all.

Comment: Suggesting polynomial long division is a completely wrong answer that misses the point of the question: a bitwise modulo. The OP even says "can we do something at the bit level?". A long division algorithm would be very long and not writable in the time frame of an interview and it does not address the bitwise data structure used. The square and multiply algorithm is the obvious answer being sought. The only problem is that, although this algorithm will be short enough, you would have to be very smart to figure it and write it in 15 minutes.

Comment: Another point to the long division dopes: long division calculates the quotient and the remainder. The problem is to calculate the REMAINDER. You can do this orders of magnitude faster and more simply than calculating the quotient.

Answer (score 0):

What you're essentially doing is binary operations.
You can look at how your CPU implements such operations.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation

Comment: Can you tell me how I'm wrong or how I didn't get it? That'll help.

I didn't really give it much thought and I answered within 10 seconds. The polynomial is really restricted so you can just essentially represent it as binary numbers and just use the algorithms for binary operations implemented by the cpu.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a simple polynomial multiplication and long division problem. Just multiply the polynomials and then divide them. Multiplication is pretty straightforward with two nested for loops, for long division see:

http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/factor/fac01/fac01.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division