# Multiplication of 2 big binary strings modulo another binary string with out converting them to Big Integer

Tags: java, security, binary, modular-arithmetic

I'm implementing a code for Advanced encryption standard(AES). I'm struck at multiplication modulo operation. The normal conversion of binary string to BigInteger is taking abnormally large amount of time. Any help as to how to code this is ??
The below link explains about the operations in finite fields.

http://www.doc.ic.ac.uk/~mrh/330tutor/ch04s04.html

Thanks in advance

As regards to bit wise operations in finite fields GF(2^m) the below stack overflow link might be helpful.
http:[Multiplying two polynomials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13202758/multiplying-two-polynomials)

Comment: It takes a large amount of time using `BigInteger` because this operation requires a lot of computation.  I doubt whether you'll find  a solution that outperforms `BigInteger`.

Comment: Is it meant for a javacard (int and long can't be used)?

Answer (score 0):

No, AES (Rijndael) involves GF(2^m) arithmetic, not integer arithmetic.  You shouldn't use BigIntegers for this -- integer arithmetic is very different than GF(2^m) arithmetic (integers have carries, finite fields do not).

If you really want to know how to do GF(2^m) arithmetic, the mathematical preliminaries section of the original Rijndael paper has a good tutorial: http://csrc.nist.gov/archive/aes/rijndael/Rijndael-ammended.pdf .  You could implemented this in bit arrays, or alternately byte arrays for those who get confused on mapping back in forth bits within bytes.  But for the love of God, please do not use BigIntegers!

However, you don't need to know much about GF(2^m) to implement AES/Rinjdael.  You do not need to do GF(2^m) arithemtic to compute the S-box of Rijndael, instead use a table lookup via a precomputed table.  That's how it is almost always implemented in practice.  Also, MixColumn is pretty trivially implemented since in the most complex case you are just multiplying by x+1, thus involving at most a single mod reduction (if you end up with an x^8, then just subtract off the irreducible polynomial, which is x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1 in AES).

Example:

```
(x^7 + x^3 + 1)*(x+1) 
= (x^7 + x^3 + 1)*x + (x^7 + x^3 + 1)*1 
= (x^8 + x^4 + x) + (x^7 + x^3 + 1)
= x^8 + x^7 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1
```

Since leading term is x^8, you must subtract off x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1 :

```
(x^8 + x^7 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1) - (x^8 + x^4 + x^3 + x + 1)
= x^7
```

That one didn't end up with negative numbers, but -1 is the same as +1 in GF(2^m) so any coefficients that are negative get turned into positive free of charge.

When you implemented this, multiply by x is just a shift left of the bit representation of the polynomial and subtraction is just an exclusive-or of bit representations of polynomials.